# set state from match.params in same component

Tags: reactjs

I have a class..

```
class App extends Component { }
```

Inside of this class I have a constructor with the following:

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {number: null, id: ""};
  }
```

Inside of the render I have a Router...

```
<Router>
   <Route path="/:id" component={Child}/>
</Router>
```

Outside of the component I have the following function

```
function Child({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>ID: {match.params.id}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If my URL is localhost:3030/12345, this will print out 12345. However, I want to be able to store 12345 in the state.

Updated:

[image]

It setting the prop correctly, but then it makes two additional calls into it and then failing with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`

```
<Router>
    <Route exact path="/:num" component={ServerCall}/>
</Router>
```

Inside of ServerCall

```
class ServerCall extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      console.log(this.props);
      this.state = {num: this.props.match.params.num};
    }

  render() {
    return (
            <div>
                {this.state.num}
            </div>
    );
  }
}


export default ServerCall;
```

Whats happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*I want to be able to store 12345 in the state*" - then you cannot use a SFC (stateless functional component). Change your `Child` into a class, initialize your `state` and set a field, e.g. `id` which will hold the value coming from props.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
   state = {
      id: this.props.match.params.id,
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h3>ID: {this.state.id}</h3>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

If you have initialized `react-router-redux` middleware and reducer, you should have a `location` field in your props. From there you can easily get the `id`. However, if you didn't do it yet, you can simply use `window.location` object to determine the url.

**Easier way**:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
   state = {
      id: '',
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      const id = window.location.pathname; // u can use regex or whatever to get just the id

      this.setState({ id });
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h3>ID: {this.state.id}</h3>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

### Note that `window` object has to be inside `componentDidMount`, not inside the constructor, because in case if you would like to implement SSR (server side rendering) in the future, you can't access the `window` object on the server side. Only on client side. `componentDidMount` happens only on client side.

Comment: If i want to remove Child, and do everything in App, can that be done?

Comment: @DroiDev Use `console.log(this.props)` in your parent and paste me what did it return. If you properly initialized `react-router-redux` middleware, you should have `location` field in props.

Comment: @DroiDev Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I decided to use another component so I can use the info from the server call in all of my components. thanks!

Comment: @DroiDev Thanks. Good luck my friend.

Comment: If you dont mind looking at my edit above and helping me out there.

Comment: @DroiDev If you are using a constructor, use `props.match.params.num` without `this`

Comment: same thing occured

Comment: @DroiDev Sir, Im in a hurry, will help you when Im at home